# changing while loop to for loop to find two people with the same birthday

Tags: python

```
import random

def findSameBDay():
    birthdays = []
    birthday = random.randint(1, 365)
    count = 1
    while birthday not in birthdays:
        count += 1
        birthdays.append(birthday)
        birthday = random.randint(1, 365)
    return count
```

I want to change the while loop to a for loop I tried converting it but I don't have a clue

Comment: or what a similar statement that can replace ( birthday not in birthdays)?

Comment: I tried birthdays[i] != birthday , it gives me a out of range index

Comment: A while loop seems appropriate here, since you don't know how many iterations are needed when the loop starts. If you had to use a for loop, you would do at most 365 iterations, but break once a match is found.

Comment: Meaning? You want to break when a number is present in list and return the number of unique gases

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: Why `count` starts in 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator,

```
import random

class BirthdayMgt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.birthdays = []
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        new_birthday = random.randint(1, 365)
        self.count += 1
        if new_birthday in self.birthdays:
            raise StopIteration
        self.birthdays.append(new_birthday)
        return new_birthday

birthday_mgt = BirthdayMgt()
for birthday in birthday_mgt:
    pass
print(birthday_mgt.count)
```

but it's gross

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:

1. Build a generator function in order to get a new random birthday each time you call it in the `for` cycle

```py
def get_birthdays():
  birthday = random.randint(1, 365)
  yield birthday
```

2. After that, you can use a recursive approach in order to re-write your `findSameBDay()`. For each number generated by `get_birthdays` (the generator), you will save it in the `birthdays` function param. The stop condition will be when the local variable `birthday` is in the list populated by the generator.

```py
def findSameBDay(birthdays=[]):
    birthday = random.randint(1, 365)
    for generator_birthday in get_birthdays():
      birthdays.append(generator_birthday)
      if birthday in birthdays:
        break
      else:
        findSameBDay(birthdays)
    return len(birthdays)

# We call the function
findSameBDay()
```